# Laravel presenting data when returning JSON

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, presenter

I have an issue with presenting data from an Eloquent model as JSON.

Let's say I have a Post model extending Eloquent. If in my route I simply return Post::find(1) I will have the following JSON :

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: "My cool blog post",
    text: "This is very interesting",
    type_id: 2
}
```

If I have an array of post types somewhere

```
$types = ["Type1", "Type2", "Type3", "Type4"];
```

How would I go adding to my json the string containing the type, transforming the string in the process (adding some exclamation marks for example) ? Expected (example):

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: "My cool blog post",
    text: "This is very interesting",
    type_id: 2,
    type_name: "!Type3!"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a Type model and define a one-to-many relationship between the Post model and the Type model